# i want to print output in a better structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have output but this is not in a proper structure

```py
import mysql.connector

myconn=mysql.connector.connect(host='-----',user='developer',passwd='----',database='pos')

cur=myconn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("select * from pos.tbl_store")
    print('ID  StoreID      Name                Type           State')
    for row in cur:
        print('%d %s  %s                %s    %s'%(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]))
except:
    myconn.rollback()
myconn.close()
```

I'm getting this

```
ID  StoreID      Name                Type           State
55 INAPHYD00036  MEDPLUS SAIDABAD               14    IN
58 INAPHYD00039  MEDPLUS DILSUKHNAGAR P&T COLONY                14    IN
64 INAPHYD00045  MEDPLUS MOTI NAGAR             14    IN
65 INAPHYD00046  MEDPLUS KPHB REMEDY HOSPITAL ROAD              14    IN
77 INAPHYD00058  MEDPLUS BOWENPALLY             14    IN
```

and expected result is:

```
ID   StoreID        Name                             Type        State
55   INAPHYD00036   MEDPLUS SAIDABAD                  14          IN
58   INAPHYD00039   MEDPLUS DILSUKHNAGAR P&T COLONY   14          IN
64   INAPHYD00045   MEDPLUS MOTI NAGAR                14          IN
```

How can I get the expected result shown above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example you can use pad right

```
h = ['ID', 'StoreID', 'Name', 'Type', 'State']
print(f'{h[0]:6}{h[1]:14}{h[2]:33}{h[3]:6}{h[4]:6}')

for row in cur:
    print(f'{row[0]:6}{row[1]:14}{row[2]:33}{row[3]:6}{row[4]:6}')
```

Comment: Thanks  @AngrySoft got output

Answer (score 4):

If you can install third-party packages then I advise `tabulate`. From your command line:

```
pip install tabulate
```

Then run:

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = ['ID', 'StoreID', 'Name', 'Type', 'State']
formatted_table = tabulate(cur, headers=headers, tablefmt='plain')
print(formatted_table)
```